# React: Problem with the text field after selecting the radiobutton

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

Hello I have a minor problem with displaying the text field after checking the "yes" radio-button in question 4
I don't see the error, until I added the submit button protection it worked.
So "requiresInput: true" does not work
I need: Answer into text field and only after answering into field the questionnaire can be sent.
Sorry but my english is not the best, but I hope it can be understood.

```js
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Question({ options, onAnswer, requiresInput }) {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleAnswer = (e, prevAnswer) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newAnswer = answer || inputValue;
    if (newAnswer !== prevAnswer) {
      onAnswer(newAnswer);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (answer !== null || inputValue !== '') {
      const newAnswer = answer || inputValue;
      onAnswer(newAnswer);
    }
  }, [answer, inputValue, onAnswer]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleAnswer(e, answer || inputValue)}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <label key={option.id}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer"
            value={option.id}
            checked={answer === option.id}
            onChange={(e) => setAnswer(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          />
          {option.text}
        </label>
      ))}
      {requiresInput && answer === 1 (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Why?"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}

function Quiz() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  const [showAnswers, setShowAnswers] = useState(false);
  
  const questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'How did you like learning in WA subject',
      options: [
        { id: 1, text: '1' },
        { id: 2, text: '2' },
        { id: 3, text: '3' },
        { id: 4, text: '4' },
        { id: 5, text: '5' },
      ],
      requiresInput: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Before the start of the year did you have experience with JS?',
      options: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Yes' },
        { id: 2, text: 'No' },
      ],
      requiresInput: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Are you interested in working with JS now?',
      options: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Yes' },
        { id: 2, text: 'No' },
      ],
      requiresInput: false,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: 'Are you interested in this topic to study something extra?',
      options: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Yes' },
        { id: 2, text: 'No' },
      ],
      requiresInput: true,
    },
  ];

  const handleAnswer = (answer, questionIndex) => {
    setAnswers(prevAnswers => {
      const updatedAnswers = [...prevAnswers];
      updatedAnswers[questionIndex] = answer;
      return updatedAnswers;
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const allQuestionsAnswered = questions.every((question, index) => {
      if (!question.requiresInput) {
        return answers[index] !== undefined;
      } else {
        return answers[index] !== undefined && answers[index] !== '';
      }
    });
    if (allQuestionsAnswered) {
      setShowAnswers(true);
    }
  };

  if (showAnswers) {
    return <Answers answers={answers} />;
  } else {
    const allQuestionsAnswered = questions.every((question, index) => {
      if (!question.requiresInput) {
        return answers[index] !== undefined;
      } else {
        return answers[index] !== undefined && answers[index] !== '';
      }
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {questions.map((question, index) => (
          <div key={question.id}>
            <h3>{question.text}</h3>
            <Question options={question.options} onAnswer={answer => handleAnswer(answer, index)} />
           
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} dis={!allQuestionsAnswered}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Answers({ answers }) {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCountdown(countdown => countdown - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (countdown === 0) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }, [countdown]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Thank you for completing the questionnaire:</h2>
      <ul>
     
      </ul>
      <p>The page will reload in {countdown} seconds...</p>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added wrong prop for disabling the button. It should be like this.

```
<button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={!allQuestionsAnswered}>
      Submit
    </button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot to finish my project.